# ¿Crear URL con Archivos de Recursos .NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Básicamente en mi RouteConfig.cs estoy intentando mapear una ruta que varíe en función del lenguaje actual del navegador.

A lo que estoy intentando llegar es a un path dinámico como:

```
/books-with-description/
/libros-con-descripcion/
```

estos strings **son constantes** (no se almacenan en db) y solo son dos (español e inglés)

Intente con:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Libros",
            url:  "{index}/index/{lang}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Libros", action = "Get", lang = UrlParameter.Optional, index = @Rurl.LibrosConDescripcion }
        );
```

Y también probé:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Libros",
            url: @Rurl.LibrosConDescripcion + "/index/{lang}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Libros", action = "Get", lang = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Siendo @Rurl.LibrosConDescripcion el acceso al string en el archivo de recursos

Por algún motivo en este caso no me esta tomando el cambio de idioma que seteo en CurrentThread.CurrentCulture. Imagino que es porque el inicio de la aplicación se ejecuta en su propio Thread y se inicia una sola vez, independientemente de los Threads creados por cada petición del navegador del cliente (Corrijanme si me equivoco).

¿Sugerencias?
¿No tengo otra opción que generar esa parte de la URL desde un ActionLink en Razor?

(La idea era setearlo una sola vez y no tener que hacerlo por cada view que quiera acceder a dicha url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por el momento logré resolverlo de esta forma:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Traer Libros", "Libros", "GetLibros", new { index = @Rurl.LibrosConDescripcion }, new { })
```

Basicamente esto me genera un tag "< a >" en HTML en mi view y dado que esta en el Thread correspondiente si cambia con respecto a la cultura.

Mi RouteConfig quedo asi:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Libros",
        url:  "{index}/index/{lang}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Libros", action = "GetLibros", lang = UrlParameter.Optional, index = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Con el problema que me encuentro ahora es, dado que este link esta en un menu general para varias paginas, **actualizar la URL que figura en el navegador** en cuando ya estoy dentro del Link mencionado, lo cual pienso hacer con javascript.

Por lo demás, esta podría ser una solución.